# Solo lectura configuración Server U5

Tags: genexus

Estoy trabajando con genexus 17 U5

es posible cambiar esta propiedad que es solo lectura, ya que me dificulta el desarrollo con esta actualizacion

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

¿No deberías cambiar la propiedad "Tomcat path" que aparece ahí arriba?

Si tienes otras versiones del Tomcat instaladas, deberían estar en otra carpeta a la que puedas referenciar.

Saludos,
Mateo